# Make PHP glob search order insensitive

Tags: php, glob

I am teaching myself php so I am sorry if this is a stupid question. I have a folder containing many folders, all of which contain JPG files. I am using the code below to search for files whose names (and/or folders names) contain ALL the keywords sent by users (limited in the example to 4 keywords). This works fine if the keywords are sent in the same order as they appear in the folder/file string but strings with the same words in a different order are not returned. How can I do this? Thank you very much!

```
<?php

$keywords = $_REQUEST['keywords'];

$exploded_keywords = explode(" ", $keywords );

if (isset($exploded_keywords[4])) { $inclusion = '*'.$exploded_keywords[0].'*'.$exploded_keywords[1].'*'.$exploded_keywords[2].'*'.$exploded_keywords[3].'*'.$exploded_keywords[4].'*'; } else { 

if (isset($exploded_keywords[3])) { $inclusion = '*'.$exploded_keywords[0].'*'.$exploded_keywords[1].'*'.$exploded_keywords[2].'*'.$exploded_keywords[3].'*'; } else { 

if (isset($exploded_keywords[2])) { $inclusion = '*'.$exploded_keywords[0].'*'.$exploded_keywords[1].'*'.$exploded_keywords[2].'*'; } else { 

if (isset($exploded_keywords[1])) { $inclusion = '*'.$exploded_keywords[0].'*'.$exploded_keywords[1].'*'; } else { 

if (isset($exploded_keywords[0])) { $inclusion = '*'.$exploded_keywords[0].'*'; }}}}}

$files = glob("$inclusion/*.[jJ][pP][gG]", GLOB_BRACE);

$num = $files[0];

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) { 
   $num = $files[$i]; 
   $err = 0;
   foreach($exclude as $term) {
      if (stristr($num,$term)) { 
         $err++; }}
   if( !$err > 0 ) { // display thumbnails... }} ?>
```

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/Y9qC25/2 note that I added mg flags to match multiple lines.

Comment: First one returns a match if ANY keywords were found.. This one will only match if ALL keywords were found : https://regex101.com/r/DjzIyf/1

Comment: *(Not related to your question)* The entire set of `if (isset($exploded_keywords...` statements can be replaced by `$inclusion = '*'.str_replace(' ', '*', $keywords).'*';` (i.e. you don't even need to `explode($keywords)`). If you need to limit the number of keywords to 5 then you can use `$exploded_keywords = explode(" ", $keywords); $inclusion = '*'.implode('*', array_slice($exploded_keywords, 0, 5)).'*';`

Comment: @axiac Would he not still have the same problem with the order of the keywords?

Comment: @Lou of course he will. I suggested a simplification of the existing code (given the OP is learning PHP). I didn't address the question.

Comment: @axiac Yes it is nice, just wanted to make sure I didn't miss something. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you both. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex to achieve this. See the last block of code for a much less self-explicative but straight forward version.

```
<?php
//Its bad practice to use $_REQUEST, you should use $_GET or $_POST if you can..
$keywords = $_REQUEST['keywords'];

//Let's prepare our regex to match our keywords.   
$exploded_keywords = explode(" ", $keywords );
$regex = "/";

//Loop trough your keywords and add them to the regex.
// ?= is a lookahead, if you want to know what it does. http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html
//preg_quote() will escape your keywords so they don't break your regex. Caracters such as ( ) . ? * etc.
foreach($exploded_keywords as $keyword){
    $regex .= "(?=.*".preg_quote($keyword, '/').")";
}

/* 
 * The following block of code has been added just in case it's useful to someone.
 * This will return a match if ANY one keyword is found within the file name. (Case insensitive)
 *
 * $regex = "/.*(";
 * $tmp = '';
 * foreach($exploded_keywords as $keyword) {
 *  $tmp = $tmp."|".preg_quote($keyword, '/');
 * }
 * $regex .= ltrim($tmp, '|') . ").*\.jpg/i";
 */
//match a jpg file. This version is case insensitive for the keywords and the extension.
$regex .=".*\.jpg/i";
//This would make it case sensitive but for the extension
//$regex .=".*\.[jJ][pP][gG]/";

//Now let's get the files
$files = glob("*.[jJ][pP][gG]", GLOB_BRACE);

//Let's get our matches
//preg_grep will look in your array values for matches and return the entries as a array. 
//array_values will reindex the keys of the returned array. Otherwise they keep their original keys. 
$matches = array_values(preg_grep($regex, $files));
//Verify your results
print_r($matches);
```

Shortened version :

```
<?php
$keywords = preg_quote($_REQUEST['keywords']);
$regex = (!empty($keywords)) ? "/(?=.*". str_replace(' ', ')(?=.*', $keywords).")"  . ".*\.[jJ][pP][gG]/" : '/.*/';
$files = glob("*.[jJ][pP][gG]", GLOB_BRACE);
$matches = array_values(preg_grep($regex, $files));
print_r($matches);
```

Edit : Added preg_quote() when generating the regex as the keywords clearly comes from user input.